# How can I send xray trace id to API gateway on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-xray

I have a lambda which has xray enabled and it sends http request to API gateway which links to another lambda. I also enabled xray in the API gateway. But it doesn't trace the whole flow because the trace id in the first lambda is not used by API Gateway.

My question is how I can send the trace id over http rest request? I'd like to link from end to end flow.

I am using `axios` in nodejs and I don't know how `awsXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal` works with this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrace the whole flow but you need manually capture the all HTTP/S external requests :

```
const awsXRay = require("aws-xray-sdk")
awsXRay.captureAWS(require("aws-sdk"))
awsXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("http"))
awsXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("https"))
```

And in your handler ( before making the HTTP request ) to allow the tracing of promise based requests ( Axios for example ) :

```
awsXRay.capturePromise()
```

Comment: Have you configured x-ray for NodeJs scripts that are not lambda or express. I could not find any samples.do you have any samples

Comment: I see you are using `http`. Does it work for `axios`?

Comment: You need to send the instrumented http/s agents in the Axios config object as follows:

`awsXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("http"))
awsXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("https"))
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')

const config = {
      httpAgent: new http.Agent(),
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent(),
      ...
    }`

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Lambda has automatic instrumentation enabled, It means the calls to aws services are tracked. But when it comes to http(s) client, explicit instrumentation is necessary.

```
var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('http'));
var http = require('http');
```

[Tracing calls to downstream HTTP web services using the X-Ray SDK for Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-httpclients.html)

Comment: How can I use it for `axios`?

Comment: I haven't done it. but you should be able to create subsegments and add meta data to capture the information. You can send the trace id manually through the http headers and receive it,  create segment on the other end.